# Simple and robust Linux command line SIP client/library

Tags: linux, command-line, voip

I'm looking for a SIP client on Linux which I could control through a pipe, or a high level library to incorporate one in my software.
I tried Linphone, which is quite good, but seems to have some instabilities, as dropping sound when talking with an Asterisk server.
I'm currently looking at OpalVoip, but I thought I'd ask to the experts...
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page [lists](http://www.pernau.at/kd/voip/bookmarks-sip-stacks.html) just about all your options. sofia and sipx are used in popular VoIP applications so they are probably good bets.

Comment: I ended up using [liblinphone](http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/dev/liblinphone-free-sip-voip-sdk.html), which is quite convenient

Answer (score 3):

I had success with Simple SIP SDK.  It seemed more modern that other solutions I tried and which did not work.  It also has OPUS support which I was looking for.

https://sipsimpleclient.org/

It is a bit of work to build from source.  They provide a repository with built binaries, which I ended up using.

After installing:

```
sip-settings -a add 6010@172.31.0.1 1234678 <--password
sip-settings -a default 6010@172.31.0.1
sip-settings -a set 6010@172.31.0.1 sip.outbound_proxy=172.31.0.1
sip-register  <-- seems optional
sip-audio-session sip:5101@172.31.0.1
```

One last note, I had to download the source to get the instructions on how to install the binaries from the repositories for the various operating systems.

Comment: incredible this works like on frist try on Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

[PJSIP](https://www.pjsip.org/) is a good choice. Very robust, stable, feature rich.